# if $ variable = string echo string - PHP - if - foreach

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

Hello everyone I'm building a business program, from a selection once the values ​​are selected, are extracted through a foreach, a result that will then be used by an employee to make a copy and paste in the description of a product:

select the product code:

```
<select name="garanzie[]" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Cerca">
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="" disabled selected>GARANZIE</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Garanzia Bagaglio">Garanzia bagaglio&nbsp;</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Assistenza in Viaggio">Assistenza in Viaggio&nbsp;</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Rimborso Spese Mediche">Rimborso Spese Mediche&nbsp;</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Assistenza alla Persona">Assistenza alla Persona&nbsp;</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Garanzia Annullanento">Garanzia Annullanento&nbsp;</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Speciale Neve">Speciale Neve&nbsp;</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Responsabilità Civile verso Terzi">Responsabilità Civile verso Terzi&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

select the supplier code:

```
<select name="compagnia_assicurativa[]" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Cerca">
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="compagnia_assicurativa[]" value="" disabled selected>COMPAGNIA ASSICURATIVA</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="compagnia_assicurativa[]" value="Nobis Assicurazioni - Filo Diretto.">Nobis Assicurazioni - Filo Diretto</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="compagnia_assicurativa[]" value="IMA Assistance Italia.">IMA Assistance Italia</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="compagnia_assicurativa[]" value="ERV.">ERV</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="compagnia_assicurativa[]" value="AIG.">AIG</option>
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="compagnia_assicurativa[]" value="ITAS MUTUA.">ITAS MUTUA</option>
</select>
```

and in this way, I take the name of the supplier + the products off-screen:

```
  <tr>
<strong>SINTETICA</strong>
<p><?php if(!empty($_POST['compagnia_assicurativa'])) {
foreach($_POST['compagnia_assicurativa'] as $compagnia_assicurativa) { ?>
<?php echo $compagnia_assicurativa . "&nbsp;-&nbsp;";  ?>
<?php    }
} ?><?php 

foreach($_POST['garanzie'] as $garanzie) {
echo $garanzie . ",&nbsp;";
}
?></p>
    </tr>
```

but now I had a specific case that in the code I wrote above only when the case is presented that the employee has chosen the guarantee:

```
<option style="font-size: 10px;" name="garanzie[]" value="Assistenza in Viaggio">Assistenza in Viaggio&nbsp;</option>
```

come out a custom value only for this choice + all the rest of the other policies with their respective values. How can I do?

Comment: You dont have to open/close php each line. All the open/close tags IN your foreach can go.

Comment: you mean if the user selects a particular option, then you want to display something different? Do you want that to happen only after they submit the form to the server, or must it happen instantly within the page? If it must be instant, then you need some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just add if statement in foreach loop. See:

```
foreach($_POST['garanzie'] as $garanzie) {
  if ($garanzie === 'Assistenza in Viaggio') {
    echo 'custom output';
  } else {
    echo $garanzie . ",&nbsp;";
  }
}
```

Please, note, that you shouldn't use `style` and `name` attributes on `option` tag. They do nothing and may confuse anyone, reading your code.